# ngx/translate - translate only part of a string

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I need to translate strings coming from a server using [ngx/translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core).

It works fine when i need to translate a string but in some case i need to translate only part of the string.

For example:
'hello Shay' or 'hello John'

And i need to translate only 'hello' and leave the name as is.
I tried:

```
this.i18n.instant('hello {Shay}')
```

and in the en.json file:
    "hello {var}": "Hello {var}"

but with no success.
Any Ideas how it can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for parametrized translations. You do not need that parameter in the translation key. Try it like this:

en.json:

```
"hello_name": "Hello {{name}}"
```

controller:

```
this.i18n.instant('hello_name', {name: 'Shay'});
```

or in template:

```
{{ 'hello_name' | translate: {name: 'Shay'} }}
```

https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#3-define-the-translations

Comment: Adamek thanks for you'r reply. you're suggestion works for me with double brackets only but is not solving my problem. The point is the key coming from the server contains the name so I don't have a permanent key like 'hello_name'. of course I can use 'hello_shay'.split('_') but I'm looking for a cleaner way to do that.

Comment: Well these two things need to be separated, you should not return it as one string from your server side. You should do it like I suggested, definitely, that is the best practice...

Comment: I do not know your use case, but your server should return you just values (like the name), it should not care about the "hello" part, that is frontend's job.

Comment: Or if you really need that, you should return something like `{message: 'hello_name', name: 'Shay'}` from your server and use `this.i18n.instant(res.message, {name: res.name});`.

Comment: I don't have control over the server so I think I'll just split the string in the client side.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about mutilple ? `this.i18n.instant(['a','b']);` where each have it's own interpulation ?

Comment: something like `['a','b'].forEach(k => this.i18n.instant(k));`?