# ngx-translate, is there a way to translate a string with multiple keys

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

If I have a translation file like:

```
{
  "PRODUCT-NAME": "My Application",
  "WELCOME": "Welcome to"
}
```

Is there a way to get ngx translate to handle something like

```
<p>{{ '{{WELCOME}} {{PRODUCT-NAME}}' | translate }}</p>
```

To clarify, I'm not looking for parameterized translations that you supply params to upon requesting the translation. This question is different from (for example) [ngx/translate - translate only part of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812294/ngx-translate-translate-only-part-of-a-string)

Edit: specifically, I wouldl like to khnow if it is possible to interpolate `{{foo}} - {{bar}}` where {{foo}} and {{bar}} come from the locale file

Comment: This one is possible <p>{{ 'WELCOME'+'PRODUCT-NAME' | translate }}</p>

Comment: Obviously for a very simple example it's possible. But if there are any decorative marks  between the two pieces of text, it won't work. Consider the following desired result:
Foo - BAR, where - is a hardcoded character that we also wish to be data driven.